# Is it a good idea to make the forward button of the browser go to the next step?

Tags: forms, navigation, wizard, back-button

I have a form / wizard on my website with multiple steps.

[image]

Pressing the back button in the browser makes you go back, so is it a good idea to make the forward button go to the next step (with JavaScript `history` API hacks)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not a good idea. Apart from the fact that nobody would expect it (principle of least surprise), it's already established that the back and forward buttons move through your browser *history* -- that is, pages that have already been visited.

The forward button also has no ability to indicate, like a 'Next' button often does, whether proceeding at this point is possible.